# Is `setState({key: value}, () => function())` the same as `setState({key:value}, function())`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any difference between using React's setState() method in the following two ways:

```
setState({key: value}, myFunction())
```

vs.

```
setState({key: value}, () => myFunction())
```

Comment: Browser support

Comment: They're both invalid javascript, I'm guessing what you meant was `function () { }`, in which case the answer is no. The first one is just passing the function as a callback, whereas the latter is passing a function which when invoked _returns_ a function.

Comment: @axiac Jack's comment referred to the code before it was edited, in which OP used `function` (a reserved word) instead of `myFunction`. The rest of your comment should be in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JordanRunning thank you, I didn't see the question in its original state. I removed my comment. Jack's comment, indeed, was correct for that state of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited to use `myFunction` as in the post).

The two  lines of code are quite different:

```
setState({key: value}, myFunction())
```

calls `myFunction` when the arguments are being evaluated, before calling `setState`. The return value of `myFunction` is then passed to `setState` as its second argument. So this version is only useful if  `myFunction()` returns a callback function for use by `setState`. If `myFunction` is the callback, however, then it's a bug which could manifest itself as the callback being called prior to the state being updated instead of afterwards.

```
setState({key: value}, () => myFunction())
```

creates an anonymous call back function which when executed returns the return value of calling `myFunction`. The arrow callback function is passed as the second argument to `setState`, without calling `myFunction` in the process.  `myFunction` will then be called after `setState` has updated the state and called the arrow function.

The second form is generally better written without creating an anonymous function intermediary:

```
setState({key: value}, myFunction)
```

Although possibly unrelated to the question, an arrow function could be used to set the `this` value of `myFunction` to the `this` value prior to the call to `setState`:

```
setState({key: value}, ()=>this.myFunction); // use current this value in the callback.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should have realized that naming the function "function" wasn't clear. I have edited the question. I also edited the question to specifically ask about React's setState() method instead of being a more general Javascript question, as that is what I had intended.